# How to update the macros when moving cells around?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macros to update the cell range W20:AH22 based the value of cell V19.

```
Sub TransferValues()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Volumes") 'Change "Sheet1" to the name of your sheet if different

    'Check if V19 equals "Base Case"
    If ws.Range("V19").Value = "Base Case" Then
        ws.Range("W20:AH22").Value = ws.Range("W39:AH41").Value
    ElseIf ws.Range("V19").Value = "High" Then
        ws.Range("W20:AH22").Value = ws.Range("W46:AH48").Value
    ElseIf ws.Range("V19").Value = "Low" Then
        ws.Range("W20:AH22").Value = ws.Range("W52:AH54").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there anyway to make this dynamic? For instance when I move the cell ranges around then can the macro follow that like an excel formula does? Thanks!

Comment: Assign the ranges to variables?

Comment: Use named ranges?

Comment: Using named ranges is a sensible step in any workbook if there is a possibility that VBA is going to interact with the workbook. It is not necessary to use VBA to create the range names - this can be done through the UI's NameManager.

Comment: How would you like to call this procedure? For example, you might call it using a one-liner `TransferValues SheetName:="Volumes", CriteriaCell:="V19", PasteRange:="W20:AH22", FirstCopyRow:=39, CopyRowOffset:=7`. What should be static and what should be dynamic? The example will, of course, only work if the row offset is consistent e.g. the last copy range is `W53:AH55`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using named range in the code, it will be dynamic as reference in formula.

```vb
Sub DefineName() ' Create named range before run TransferValues
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Volumes")
'    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Range("W39:AH41").Name = "Base_Case"
    ws.Range("W46:AH48").Name = "High"
    ws.Range("W52:AH54").Name = "Low"
    ws.Range("W20:AH22").Name = "Destination"
End Sub

Sub TransferValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sVal
    call DefineName
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Volumes")
'    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    sVal = Replace(ws.Range("V19").Value, " ", "_")
    If InStr("Base_Case|High|Low", sVal) > 0 Then
        ws.Range("Destination").Value = ws.Range(sVal).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. When I assign this to a button and press run it does not update the ranges!

Comment: I have updated the code. Pls assign `TransferValues()` to a button.